# makefile in c using linux

Tags: c++, makefile

I have made a makefile, but it is not working properly, it's showing fatal error.

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -wall -g

all:main

main: main.o Point.o Rectangle.o

    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main main.o Point.o Rectangle.o

main.o: main.cpp Point.h Rectangle.h

    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

Point.o: Point.h

Rectangle.o: Rectangle.h Point.h

clean:
    rm *o main
```

Comment: Please show the whole error message, and how you invoke `make`.

Comment: You have to tell how to create your `.o` files. `Point.o: Point.h`
 will do nothing. You have to `$(CXX) -o Point.o -c Point.c $(CXXFLAGS)` under it with a tab

Comment: There could be implicit rules. The makefile as such looks OK to me, assuming the tabs are in the right places.

Comment: @Hearner: You are wrong! It is enough to tell that main depends on some other objects. make itself has implicit rules how to create a .o file from different source types

Comment: the line "$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp" makes no sense for me. Also all the NEEDED indentation is missing. It must be tabs!

Comment: Do you have `Point.cpp`? Of so, you are missing it. If not, you probably shouldn't have `Point.o` rule. Header files generally aren't compiled on their own. Also, show is what commands make invokes and what you would expect instead. If the commands are what you expect but they fail, then this is not makefile problem, show is your code and how you compile it instead, and the error message.

Comment: @Hearner, @Klaus Yes, the implicit rules are (often) fine, but here should be a dependency on the source file as well: `Point.o: Point.cpp Point.h`. And `Rectangle.o: Rectangle.cpp Rectangle.h Point.h`

Comment: Or, as @Hearner implies: if `Point` and `Rectangle` are fully defined in the header files, you should not have any compilation rules for them (i.e., there will be no `.o` files created).
@Yash: you may want to clarify what source files you do have in order to remove the guesswork from the answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.  BTW, `-wall` looks like a typo for `-Wall`, and `rm` for `$(RM)`; you don't need those compilation commands - just leave out the commands to use the default built-in rules, and add `main: LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)` to select the correct linker.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you want:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g
all:main

main: main.o Point.o Rectangle.o
    $(LINK.cpp) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^

clean:
    rm *.o main
```

The above assume you have source files: `main.cpp`, `Point.cpp` and `Rectangle.cpp` in the same folder.  I also updated `-wall` to be `-Wall` and used tabs for indenting. I forget the rules on indenting, but I just made everything above indent with tabs to be consistent with my own Makefiles that work.

Comment: Why you repeat an already existing implicit rule? You should also add the dependencies again! And the clean rule is also suboptimal. It is quite common to use '-f' to get not an error if the files do not exist.

Comment: This misses that `Rectangle.o` depends on `Point.h`